# When should we choose to throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns, throws

When should we chose to throws an exception?

```
 public Something sqlQuery(String sqlQuer) throws SqlException {

 }
```

We can catch this exception in try catch.

In which situation does we choose to use throws instead of catching immediately? is it some design pattern related?

Comment: Do you understand what an Exception is? It is an "abnormal termination of an application". Can your system recover from the error, and keep on working? catch it. can't it? throw.

Comment: Handle an exception if you can do something reasonable as a result of that exception. Otherwise, just let callers decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If a method (M1) has the capability to handle an exception by itself, then use try-catch-finally. 
If not, throw it. The calling method (M2) now has to handle a potential exception of M1 or throw it itself.

Beside of this, all Expections expect of RuntimeExceptions require to be catched.

Comment: "then use try-catch-finally" why finally?